Prove that 3COLORHC is NP-complete using Hamiltonian Cycle
We know that the language of undirected graphs that contain a Hamiltonian cycle is NP-complete
we need to use this to prove that the following language is NP-complete (I know how to prove that it is in NP, I'm looking for the polynomial reduction)
$3COLORHC = \{ <G> | \text{ G is an undirected graph that can be 3 colored} \\ \text{and also contains a Hamiltonian cycl}e \}$

We discourage posts that simply contain the statement of an exercise-style task.  Our goal is to build an archive of knowledge that will be useful to others in the future, and a list of exercises and their solutions might not advance that mission much.  We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find this page helpful in improving your question.

You might try listing what progress you've made, provide context about where you encountered this task (can you credit the original source?), and ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the same problem you happen to be working on.

One simple way to deal with your problem is to make the $3$-colorable constraint trivially satisfiable. An intuitive approach is to introduce additional vertices such that the graph is always $3$-colorable without compromising the Hamiltonian cycle constraint.

 Hint: split the vertices into multiple parts

